# Matrix as tensor exercise with answer

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Can I get an explanation for the following exercise with answer in the book *Linear Algebra via Exterior Products* by S. Winitzki?

> **Exercise 1 - Matrices as Tensors.** Now suppose you have a matrix $A_{jk}$ that specifies the linear operator $\hat A$ in a basis $\{\mathbf e_k\}.$ Which tensor $A\in V\otimes V^*$ corresponds to this operator?
>   **Answer:**
>   $$A=\sum_{j,k=1}^n\,A_{jk}\,\mathbf e_j\otimes \mathbf e_k^*.$$

A tensor of the form $\mathbf e_j \otimes\mathbf e_k^*$ is presumably a $(1,1)$-tensor, and should take a covector and a vector. But if it represents a matrix, then it is only taking in a vector...

Say the matrix is $$\mathbf A=\begin{bmatrix}6&7&1\\-2&0&10\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then, it would just need a vector to implement the linear transformation. For example, $\small\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\1\end{bmatrix}.$

Aren't the columns of the matrix $\mathbf A$ expressed in the the basis $\mathbf e_k^*$ as in

$$\mathbf A=\begin{bmatrix}6 \mathbf e_{11}^*&7\mathbf e_{12}^*&1\mathbf e_{13}^*\\-2\mathbf e_{21}^*&0\mathbf e_{22}^*&10\mathbf e_{23}^*\end{bmatrix}$$

in some fashion? What goes with $\mathbf e_j$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Interesting... I went on the assumption that it gave it some authenticity by showing that it comes from an actual publication, and that careless mistakes in transcription, etc, were out of the question. I did  typed it into LaTeX and got rid of the image.

Comment: Thanks for [edit].  I've upvoted for your correct way of [handling images containing text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141752/259305).  Giving the book title, author name and the section/page number suffices for authenticity.  In fact, the [SE network *doesn't* want "text images"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305) since *they aren't SEO friendly*.

Comment: @GNUSupporter No problem. Consider answering the question if you are comfortable with the topic.

Comment: Thanks for invitation, but sorry... I dunno ([tag:tensors]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the basic insights of multilinear algebra is that "taking a vector" is in some sense equivalent to "giving you a covector" (because taking a vector is what that covector *does*), and conversely "taking a covector" is the same as "giving you a vector".

So we can view an $(1,1)$-tensor *either* as something that takes in a vector and a covector (and gives you a scalar back), or as something that takes a vector and gives you another vector back. Not coincidentally, these are also two things you can do with a matrix: Given $A$ you can either take a column $v$ and a row $z^T$ and compute the scalar $z^T A v$, or you can take just the column $v$ and compute the column $Av$.

In particular, $w\otimes u^*$ can represent the operation that

- takes in a vector $v$.
- computes a scalar contracting $u^*$ and $v$.
- returns that scalar times $w$.

If you *also* give it a covector $z^*$, you can contract that with the result of the above operation and get a scalar. This gives the *same* scalar as if you contracted the input vector and covector separately:

$$ \langle z^*, \langle u^*,v\rangle w \rangle = \langle u^*, v\rangle\langle z^*, w\rangle  $$
by (right) linearity of the inner product.

Comment: The explanation makes sense in general, but I still don't see the answer provided in the question. Let me ask you... When you say "Given $A$ you can either take a column $v$ and a row $z^T$" are you referring to columns and rows of the matrix, or to column and row vectors different to the matrix? In other words, it is about the notation (mainly).

Comment: @justquestions: $v$ and $z^T$ are arbitrary column and row vectors (of the right dimension).

Comment: In particular $(\mathbf e_i\otimes \mathbf e_j^*)$ represents the operator that maps $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)$ to $(0,\ldots,0,a_j,0,\ldots,0)$, where $i$ determines where in the output vector the $a_j$ goes.

Comment: If I read you properly, you are saying that $\mathbf A$ is a (1,1)-tensor. So you can feed this thing a $[3\times 1]$ column vector, and it will spit out (sorry about the visuals, here) a $[2\times 1] $ column vector. Or you can feed it a covector (which is -wink, wink- a $[1 \times 2]$ row vector in disguise to weed out the uninitiated), and it will spit out a $[1 \times 3$ row vector (covector). Or you can overfeed the beast with both a vector (column vector) and covector (row vector), to get a number.

Comment: And "contracting" stands for regular linear algebra operations?

Comment: @justquestions: Yes, that's right. [Contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction) is a basic tensor operation that takes a $(n,m)$-tensor to a $(n-1,m-1)$ tensor. It's what takes the outer product $u\otimes u^*$ to the inner product $\langle u^*,v\rangle$; for matrices it produces the _trace_ of the matrix.